# MySQL result to a PHP array

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo

I'm trying to get a json array of this format :

```
var js_array = [
   ["Name1", "Address1", "Url1"],
   ["Name2", "Address2", "Url2"],
   etc...
]
```

from a MySQL query.
Here is my database :

```
+---------+-------------+---------+
|   Name  |   Address   |   URL   |
+---------+-------------+---------+
|  Name1  |  Address1   |   Url1  |
|  Name2  |  Address2   |   Url2  |
|  Name3  |  Address3   |   Url3  |
+---------+-------------+---------+
```

I tried this :

```
$query = $bdd->query('SELECT Name, Adress, URL FROM festivals');
while ($row = $query->fetch()) {
    $array[] = $row['Name'];
    $array[] = $row['Adress'];
    $array[] = $row['URL'];
}
//Then I return it as an js array that I use later
$js_array = json_encode($array);
```

The result is :

```
["Name1", "Address1", "Url1", "Name2", "Address2", "Url2", "Name3", "Address3", "Url3"]
```

I also tried this :

```
$query = $bdd->query('SELECT Name, Adress, URL FROM festivals');
while ($row = $query->fetch()) {
    $array[] = $row;
}
//Then I return it as an js array that I use later
$js_array = json_encode($array);
```

Which returns this :

```
[
 {0: "Name1", 2: "Address1", 2: "Url1", Name: "Name1", Address: "Address1", URL: "Url1"},
 {0: "Name2", 2: "Address2", 2: "Url2", Name: "Name2", Address: "Address2", URL: "Url2"}
]
```

Is there a way to get what I'd like ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to create an array for each row which has only the values in it:

```
$query = $bdd->query('SELECT Name, Adress, URL FROM festivals');
while ($row = $query->fetch()) {
    $array[] = array($row['Name'], $row['Adress'], $row['URL']);
}
//Then I return it as an js array that I use later
$js_array = json_encode($array);
```

Comment: Or you could just do `fetchAll()`, which does the same thing.

Comment: @Mike OPs second test case is equivalent to `fetchAll()` and yields the wrong results. See for example [PDOStatement::fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

Comment: @Nick That's because the fetch style defaults to `PDO::FETCH_BOTH`. To get a numeric indexed, just do `$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM)`.